# Integrating Formula of spherical cap volume with respect to $h$

Tags: integration, volume

Context: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/MoreVolume.aspx (Example 3)

When integrating the spherical cap volume formula, Paul comes up with the following solution:

$V=\int_{r-h}^{r}\pi(r^2-y^2)dy=\pi\left(r^2y-\frac{1}{3}y^3\right)\biggr\rvert_{r-h}^{r}=\pi\left(h^2r-\frac{1}{3}h^3\right)=\pi h^2 \left(r-\frac{1}{3}h\right)$

**Question:** Whats going on here?*

---

This is my result:

$V=\int_{r-h}^{r}\pi(r^2-y^2)dy=\pi\left(r^2y-\frac{y^3}{3}\right)\biggr\rvert_{r-h}^{r}=\pi\left[\left(r^2\cdot r-\frac{r^3}{3}\right)- \left(r^2(r-h)-\frac {(r-h)^3}{3} \right )\right]$

$=\pi\left[\left(r^3-\frac{r^3}{3}\right)-\left(r^3-r^2 h-\frac{\color{red} {r^3-3hr^2+3h^2r-h^3}} {3}\right )\right]$

I had  to stop here because my solution is very far from the one above.

*Sorry for the informal question

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Another way to get Paul's answer is to substitute $u=r-y$ to get $V=\int_0^h\pi(r^2-(r-u)^2)du=\int_0^h \pi(2ru-u^2)du$.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution was not very far from the one above.  Let's group terms inside the square brackets, by powers of $r$:

We have $$r^3\left( 1 - \frac13 -(1-\frac13) \right) = 0 \cdot r^3$$
And
$$ r^2 \left( 0 - (-h + \frac{3h}{3}) \right) = 0 \cdot r^2$$
And
$$r \left( -(-3\frac{h^2}{3} \right) = rh^2$$
And 
$$ \left( -( -( -\frac{h^3}{3} )) \right) =  - \frac13 h^3 $$

So the answer is $$\pi\left[rh^2 - \frac13 h^3 \right] =  \pi h^2 \left( r - \frac13 h\right)$$

Comment: Where did $(r-h)$ go in step one?